# How can I increase the number of cards per row using react-bootstrap <CardColumns> component?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am struggling a bit with how to format React-Bootstraps `<CardColumns>` component.

It appears no matter what size my cards are, they will only put 3/row but I am trying to get like 4/5 per row. I am just using the basic component with no extra css. How can I force it to put more cards there?

```
<CardColumns style={{padding:20}}>
        {featuredData1.map(function(featuredListing, i){
                    return <ListingCard key={i} listingData={featuredListing}/>
        })}
```

the `<Listing Card>` component is just my own using the `<card>` component.

Also - when I modify the number of cards to display, and it is not an even multiple of 3, it only puts 2 on the last two rows rather than just 3 on one row, and 1 on the other? How can I force it so that it does 3+1 rather than 2+2? I am trying to create a product listing page. Here is what I am talking about

[trying to get 2 even rows of 3 and one row of 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15kQp.png)

Comment: won't answer your question but css grids are now ways more efficient, clean and easy to use instead of bootstrap flex-based grid. it might solve your problem in the end (http://cssgridgarden.com/)

Comment: like these? https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp

Comment: yes . provided link will show you how to use them with a little funny game. looking at the picture you sent I guess it will be better than using bootstrap grid